# Convergence in probability in a random point

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

In general I am trying to solve this problem:
I know:

$f_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ in probability for all $x  \in I$, $I$ is compact interval. $X$ is random variable with density in $I$. Can I prove, that:

$f_{n}(X) \rightarrow f(X)$ in probability?

To be specific my original problem is about asymptotic mean square error of local linear estimator conditioned by $X=(X_{1}, \ldots , X_{n})$:

$MSE[\hat{m}_{LL}(x)| X]=O_{P}(h^{4}_{n}+\frac{1}{nh_{n}})  \stackrel{?}{\Rightarrow}$
$MSE[\hat{m}_{LL}(X_{i})| X]=O_{P}(h^{4}_{n}+\frac{1}{nh_{n}})$.

Thanks in advance for any help.